# How to transform SQL WHERE clause to get tuple which includes NULL values?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have some problems by filtering a specific dataset from my database table (I use an **Oracle** database). Here is my table (the column **MAX_END_DATE** was calculated by an subsselct statement):

```
ID    |     Quarter      |       BEGINN_DATE      |      END_DATE      |      MAX_END_DATE
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
21    |     01.01.2019   |       09.01.2019       |        NULL        |        09.01.2019
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
22    |     01.01.2019   |       03.01.2019       |     09.01.2019     |        09.01.2019
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
23    |     01.01.2019   |       02.01.2019       |     03.01.2019     |        09.01.2019
```

**If the value NULL exists** in the column END_DATE I want to get this tuple. **But If no NULL Value exists** in this column, I want to get the tuple, which includes the MAX_DATE in the column END_DATE.
To solve this problem, I have written the following Where clause:

```
SELECT *
FROM myTable
WHERE end_date IS NULL
OR(
end_date IS NOT NULL AND
end_date = max_end_datum
);
```

With this WHERE Clause I get the following result:

```
ID    |     Quarter      |       BEGINN_DATE      |      END_DATE      |      MAX_END_DATE
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
21    |     01.01.2019   |       09.01.2019       |        NULL        |        09.01.2019
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
22    |     01.01.2019   |       03.01.2019       |     09.01.2019     |        09.01.2019
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

How I must transform the WHERE Clause to get the the tuple with the value NULL, when this value exists in the column END_DATE?

I want to get only this result If Null value exists in column END_DATE:

```
ID    |     Quarter      |       BEGINN_DATE      |      END_DATE      |      MAX_END_DATE
 ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
21    |     01.01.2019   |       09.01.2019       |        NULL        |        09.01.2019    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I want to get only this result If no null value exists in column END_DATE:

```
 ID    |     Quarter      |       BEGINN_DATE      |      END_DATE      |      MAX_END_DATE
    ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------    
 22    |     01.01.2019   |       03.01.2019       |     09.01.2019     |        09.01.2019
    ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I don´t want to get both result simultaneously. I want get get the first result OR the secons result.

Thanks for help !

//EDIT:

I forget to mention, that values in the column quarter can be variable und must not be the first Day of any quarter:

```
  ID    |     Quarter      |       BEGINN_DATE      |      END_DATE      |      MAX_END_DATE
```

---

```
  21    |     01.01.2019   |       01.01.2019       |     20.02.2019     |        21.02.2019
 ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  22    |     21.02.2019   |       21.02.2019       |     21.02.2019     |        21.01.2019
    ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  23    |     21.02.2019   |       22.02.2019       |       NULL         |        21.01.2019
```

Comment: It's not clear the current output is not what you want. Please post your desired output.

Comment: Result you got "with this WHERE clause" matches what you posted (while editing the question) as desired result - both results contain rows with ID = 21 and 22, so ... what's the problem?

Comment: I only need the first result with null value, if it exists

Answer (score 0):

You can use the NVL Function https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/nvl.php to replace NULL value with a string or character.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `analytical function` as follows:

```
SELECT *
FROM ( SELECT T.*,
              SUM(CASE WHEN END_DATE IS NULL THEN 1 END) 
                OVER( PARTITION BY QUARTER) NULLCNT
         FROM MYTABLE T)
WHERE
    ( NULLCNT = 1 AND END_DATE IS NULL )
    OR ( NULLCNT = 0 AND END_DATE = MAX_DATE )
```

Comment: Great!  Many thanks. I have complement the following Codeline: SUM(CASE WHEN END_DATE IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)

Comment: If this answer solved your question then please [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it, so that your question is marked as resolved.

Comment: sorry, but your solution only works, if the column quarter includes different values. If the column quarter includes the same values, it doesn´t work

Comment: Is there a way to work without the column quarter in the OVER and PARTITION BY clause?

Comment: replace `OVER( PARTITION BY QUARTER)` with `OVER()`

Comment: show me the sample data, actual and expected result. according to sample data given in the question, It should work

Comment: Hi, I have completed my question with an example. Please have a look at the section "Edit" at the end of my question. Thanks !

Comment: Do you have any idea?